# How can we use search for a file under particular directory in ant

Tags: ant

Hi all this is my code for checking if a particular file is present e.g. `${file}=license`

```
<target name="File.check" >
   <condition property="File.exists" >
      <available file="${File}" type="file" />
    </condition>
```

although if the file present is exactly license it works fine but sometimes the file can be either license.txt or even in uppercase also.

So I want my above code to work under all conditions even if the file is License or LICENSE or license or LICENSE.txt or anything that starts with l or L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<target name="SearchForfile">
    <delete dir="../filepresent" />
        <copy todir="../filepresent" failonerror="yes" flatten="true">
            <fileset dir="../result/unzip/${param1}" casesensitive="false"> 
                <include name="**/*license*"/> 
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    <antcall target="CheckFileExistance"/>  
</target>
```

in that `"CheckFileExistance"` target just check if `"filepresent"` folder is present or not if it is then the file is present in your source directory and else if `"filepresent"` folder is not there that means file is not present anywhere in your search directory...i  hope this makes everything clear

Answer (score 1):

It probably would be easiest to include all possible variations, as the [file attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600915/how-can-we-use-search-for-a-file-under-particular-directory-in-ant) needs a real file and does not allow wildcards:

```
 <condition property="File.exists" >
    <or>
      <available file="license.txt" type="file" />
      <available file="LICENSE.txt" type="file" />
      <available file="license" type="file" />
      <available file="LICENSE" type="file" />
    </or>
 </condition>
```

The other possibility is to [write your own condition](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/custom-programming.html).

Comment: i think better approach was to use regex and copy the file to some folder but that folder should be created iff the files and everytime you need to check now only for if this folder exists that did wonders for me..i hope it helps you also

Comment: @user1387014 if you have a better solution, please post this as an answer(with all the details!) for future visitors. You can even accept this answer later

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Contains](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html#contains) condition to check whether `${file}` contains the text "license". It even has a `casesensitive` argument. Not sure whether

> anything that starts with l or L

is a good idea though.